# Validar con expresion regular python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con python y estoy realizando un chat, necesito validar que si el usuario cuando envie un código de la siguiente manera:

Código 1: ZH150000001

Código 2: ZHS150000001

Validar si empieza con ZH o ZHS y lo que le sigue es un numero.

Pienso que si se podría con una expresion regular pero no estoy seguro.

De ser asi, saben de alguna? o de algún generador de expresiones regulares entendible?.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás en lo cierto, una expresión regular validaría esto. Por ejemplo, la siguiente expresión regular valida lo que comentas

```
^ZHS?\d+$
```

Paso a explicarte cada cosa

- `^ZH` Esto obliga a que el texto empiece (esto se marca con `^`) con `ZH`
- `S?` Esto indica que la letra `S` es opcional (puede venir, o no)
- `\d+` significa cualquier dígito, repetido 1 o más veces (no hemos puesto límite)
- `$` indica que es el final del texto leído, no debe continuar con más texto detrás.

Un ejemplo rápido para probar dicha expresión regular en python sería:

```
re.match(r'^ZHS?\d+$', 'ZH150000001')
```

Se me olvidaba comentar, si esto devuelve `None`, es que no ha habido coincidencia, si devuelve una referencia, es que si la ha encontrado

Comment: Me funciono excelente, pero hay forma de que la ZH o ZHS pueda ser en mayuscula o minuscula, osea que acepte ambos?

Comment: Claro, tienes varias alternativas:

1- convertir a mayúsculas todo antes de hacer nada, y comparas siempre en mayúsculas

2- Hacer una expresión regular que tenga ambas opciones (algo como `ZH|zh`

3- Pedirle al propio `match` que ignore mayúsculas, sería algo como: `re.match(r'^ZHS?\d+$', 'ZH150000001', re.IGNORECASE)`

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular que buscas es `(ZHS?\d+)`. Te la explico por partes:

Las paréntesis delimitan un segmento a buscar. No son estrictamente necesarias pero si no las ponen "match" no te devolverá lo que encuentre.

Las letras son lo que son, `Z`, luego `H` y luego `S`. La `S` va seguida de una interrogación que significa "0 ó 1".

Luego viene `\d`, que significa "dígito", es decir, del 0 al 9. El signo `+` que va detrás indica que debe haber una serie de 1 o más.

En esta página puedes probar tus expresiones regulares en Python: https://pythex.org/